# Primefaces - Cant find method when passing parameter to action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to pass parameters to my backing bean using action (testPlan and rowIndex). But when I run the code it says it can't find the method.

```html
<p:commandLink update=":scriptGroupPopupID" ajax="true"
               action="#{workloadScripts.initCurrentGroup(testPlan, rowIndex)}"
               immediate="true"
               oncomplete="PF('scriptGroupPopup').show();">
    <f:param name="insertIndex" value="#{rowIndex}" /> 
</p:commandLink>
```

```java
public void initCurrentGroup(String testPlan, String rowIndex) {
    ...
}
```

However, if I remove the parameters from `initCurrentGroup` method only, it does work. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The type of the `rowIndexVar` variable is an `int`. You must use a matching method signature. Assuming `testPlan` is indeed a `String`, you should use:

```java
public void initCurrentGroup(String testPlan, int rowIndex) {
    ...
}
```

Which you can use like:

```html
<p:commandLink update=":scriptGroupPopupID"
               action="#{workloadScripts.initCurrentGroup(testPlan, rowIndex)}"
               process="@this"
               oncomplete="PF('scriptGroupPopup').show();" />
```

Please note that I've removed `ajax="true"` (which is default), and replaced `immediate="true"` with `process="@this"`.

See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)